# jQuery appends HTML element but also displays code after

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm doing an Ajax call and rendering one of two templates depending on the response. The correct template will render, but the rest of the script renders after it on the page verbatim. See code below. Please note that the first part of the below code is in an Ajax success function, and up until the beginning of the quote everything works as expected:

```
if (questionAnswered == true) {
          $('#dashboard-container').innerHTML("<div>{{ template "header.html" .}}</div><div>{{ template "dashboard_answered.html" .}}</div>");
        }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('Diary GET failure--there are no diaries');
    }
  });
```

`dashboard_answered.html` correctly renders, but then so does everything from the closing `"` on immediately thereafter. So I end up with a bunch of text on my page that is just code. I've tried everything I can think of and scoured Stack Overflow to no avail. This included escaping the nested quotation marks within the appended HTML.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the code between {{ }} ? Are you using a templating engine?

Comment: try using backticks instead of ""

Comment: I'm using a Golang backend that handles the templating. Not sure if this is a part of Golang itself or not...I used [this](https://github.com/Massad/gin-boilerplate) as my boilerplate.

Comment: Backticks didn't solve it.

Comment: Do a View Source in the browser. That will show you the actual HTML/JavaScript code the browser sees. You can add that to your question in a code block. The browser doesn't know anything about your Go templates, only the HTML/CSS/JavaScript they generate.

Comment: I have since determined that the best way forward is to significantly refactor my code so that the use of jQuery is not necessary in this instance. I have solved my problem by doing so.

What is the accepted practice for this kind of situation on Stack Overflow? Should I delete the question? I don't have the original code around to easily test without reverting to earlier commits.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using single quotes to enclose the whole string, and double quotes within:

```
if (questionAnswered == true) {
          $('#dashboard-container').innerHTML('<div>{{ template "header.
html" .}}</div><div>{{ template "dashboard_answered.html" .}}</div>');
        }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('Diary GET failure--there are no diaries');
    }
  });
```

Comment: @223seneca how about surrounding it with double quotes but using singles or backtick inside?